# "getDefaultSmsPackage(this)==null" on android 4.4

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat

```
Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this)==null
```

Why? Is there no default SMS app in the phone or other reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user use the app on his tablet .